# resize image - showing only half if the pic

Tags: php

this script some how showing half of the image not the whole image... i am trying to figure this out what is wrong here

any help please

// The file

```
                        $ftimage = $_POST['feature_image'];

                        // maximum height 150 X width 150
                        $width = 150;
                        $height = 150;


                        // Dimensions Set
                        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($ftimage);

                        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

                        if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
                           $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
                        } else {
                           $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
                        }

                        // Resample
                        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($ftimage);
                        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

                        // Output
                        $image = imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
                        var_dump($image);
```

Comment: Did you try with different images? Same result for everyone?

Comment: output `$width_orig` and `$height_orig` and see if that is right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace it

```
$ftimage = $_POST['feature_image'];
```

with it:

```
$ftimage = $_POST['feature_image']['tmp_name'];
```

Or if in your POST request stores a URL of remote image, try something like that:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($ftimage));
```

Comment: I think there is no file uploading here